# Emulate mouse scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jquery-events

I'm using Jack Moore's [Wheelzoom](http://www.jacklmoore.com/wheelzoom/) jQuery plugin to zoom and drag an SVG image.

However, I also need to implement manual zoom in and out buttons.

The two options I can think of are to trigger a mouse wheel event on the image when a button is clicked or add a button click handler to the plugin. As far as I'm aware, you can't specify a direction when triggering a mouse wheel event and I'm really not sure how to go about adding a button click handler to the plugin.

Any help with either of those options would be greatly appreciated.

I did try this, but doesn't seem to do anything:

```
$('#site-viewer img').wheelzoom();

var mouseWheelUp = $.Event('DOMMouseScroll', {delta: 1});
var mouseWheelDown = $.Event('DOMMouseScroll', {delta: -1});

$('#zoom-in').click(function() {
    $('#site-viewer img').trigger(mouseWheelUp);
});

$('#zoom-out').click(function() {
    $('#site-viewer img').trigger(mouseWheelDown);
});
```

EDIT: If I replace 'DOMMouseScroll' with 'mousewheel', since I'm using Chrome, it is able to zoom out on click, but it does that for the zoom in button as well. Am I specifying the delta correctly? Is there a different way of specifying direction?

Answer (score 1):

Emulate mousewheel is not good idea. Better to look at plugin source code and understand how it works.

```
jQuery(function($){

    var image = $('img').wheelzoom();
    var onwheel = document.onmousewheel ? 'onmousewheel' : 'onwheel';

    $('#zoomin').click(function(){
        image.get(0)[onwheel]($.Event('mousewheel', {
            "deltaY": -1,
            "pageX": image.offset().left + (image.width() / 2),
            "pageY": image.offset().top + (image.height() / 2)
        }));
    });

    $('#zoomout').click(function(){
        image.get(0)[onwheel]($.Event('mousewheel', {
            "deltaY": 1,
            "pageX": image.offset().left + (image.width() / 2),
            "pageY": image.offset().top + (image.height() / 2)
        }));
    });
});
```